# Downloading a PDF from a Blob URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

In this situation, I am using Nightwatch.js

I am served a page containing something similar to blob:https://somethingcool.com/1asdf123948asdf in which is a PDF.

I have tried http methods, along with some NPM PDF download packages, but none of them support blob.

Any ideas?

Comment: try this `var url = URL.createObjectURL(yourBlob);
window.open(url);`

Comment: Here is the code I am using, although, not sure what it is accomplishing. The test does nothing and continues. `browser.url((result) => {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(result.value);
    window.open(url);
})`

Comment: You always want to edit your question and post any relevant info there (like the code you just added). You don't want future readers to have to dig through all the comments to get all the info they need to answer the question.